# Wordpress Woocommerce - User Billing Meta Update

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I currently have this working example.
Everything but the woocommerce meta gets updated.

Is my syntax incorrect? ( rgar is a gravity form function that returns escaped form value )

```
$user_id = wp_create_user( $username, $password, rgar( $entry, '4' ) );
wp_update_user( array( 
    'ID'                   => $user_id, 
    'role'                 => 'customer', //works
    'first_name'           => rgar( $entry, '1.3' ),  //works
    'last_name'            => rgar( $entry, '1.6' ),  //works
    'billing_first_name'   => rgar( $entry, '1.3' ), 
    'billing_last_name'    => rgar( $entry, '1.6' ),
    'show_admin_bar_front' => 'false', //works
    'billing_email'        => rgar( $entry, '4' ), 
    'billing_address_1'    => rgar( $entry, '3.1' ), 
    'billing_city'         => rgar( $entry, '3.3' ), 
    'billing_state'        => rgar( $entry, '3.4' ), 
    'billing_postcode'     => rgar( $entry, '3.5' ),
    'billing_phone'        => rgar( $entry, '6' )
));
update_field('field_5629452b8c7de', rgar( $entry, '1.3' ) . ' ' . rgar( $entry, '1.6' ), 'user_' . $user_id); //works
update_field('field_5629455f8c7df', rgar( $entry, '9' ), 'user_' . $user_id); //works
update_field('field_569e4be42ab47', rgar( $entry, '8' ), 'user_' . $user_id); //works
update_field('field_569e4c192ab48', str_replace('-', '', rgar( $entry, '7' )), 'user_' . $user_id); //works
```

Comment: Do you mean everything but woocommerce meta DOES get updated?

Comment: @Dan yes the woocommerce meta is left blank

Comment: Ok cool, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the things you are trying to update in `wp_update_user()` are `user_meta` fields, rather than `user` fields.

... So, you need to use:

```
update_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value );
```

There are a few `user_meta` fields that `wp_update_user()` will automatically recognise and save in the right way, but Woocommerce's custom ones are not included there.

So you need to update your code accordingly, to use `update_user_meta()`. E.g.:

```
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_postcode', rgar( $entry, '3.5' ) );
```

Check here to see all `user_meta` fields that you can pass to the `wp_update_user()` function (same as those that you can pass to the `wp_insert_user()` function -https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user#Notes